# Display certain categories for Opencart

Tags: php, opencart, categories

I have been looking for the last 2 days for a solution to this but I can't seem to find one. Basically I want to split my menu up and have categories 1-4 on one side and then 5-8 on another side. I just can't seem to work out the code to display 1-4 categories for example.

I'm using v1.5.4.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, if you are using a set number of categories you could just use a simple couple of loops

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    if(empty($categories[$i])) continue;
    $cat = $categories[$i];
    // Work with $cat here for each category item
}
?>
```

That will loop through the first four categories in the category array. For the second loop, do the same thing replacing `= 0` with `= 4` and `< 4` with `< 9`

Comment: Thats perfect Jay, Thanks! How would I do something similar to the above but this time include say category id 1,3,4,7?

Comment: Instead of trying to get specific categories you should instead use the sort order for categories, and set up the first four accordingly